# How to use jquery to progressively modify Translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page I have this bit of code that will reduce the padding of the site header element proportionally to amount of scroll.

```
var $header = jQuery('.site-header'),
padding = parseInt($header.css('padding'));

jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
    $header.css({
      padding: padding -$(window).scrollTop()
   });
});
```

How can I change this so in the same way it will translate an element downwards proportionally with the scroll?

It seems easy with padding, but how would I write out "transform: translate(0px,0px)" so that only the Y is translated?

***NEW****

```
var $banner = jQuery('.main-banner'),
transform = parseInt($banner.css('transform').split(',')[5]);

jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
 $banner.css({
    transform: 'translateY' +$(window).scrollTop()
  });
});
```

Comment: okay so the first half seems to be fine and its able to actually find the value, but now i cant for the life of me get it to calculate the tranlsate based on scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so i finally got this to work!

```
 var $banner = jQuery('.main-banner'),
 transform = parseInt($banner.css('transform').split(',')[5]);

 jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
   $banner.css({
   "transform": "translateY("+ transform + $(window).scrollTop() +"px)"
   });
 });
```

Now the fun part is getting it to stop after certain amount of scroll :P